# How to Store a User-defined Class Object in Sql Server 2008 using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save byte[] into a SQL Server database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp)

I have a class named **LeaveDetails.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LeaveMgmt_14dec
{
    [Serializable]
    public class LeaveDetails
    {
        public string date;
        public string leave_type;
    }
}
```

Then a created a List of Objects of LeaveDetails Class.

```
List<LeaveDetails> Details = new List<LeaveDetails>();
```

Now I Serialised it and stored it in the datababse, i.e. , Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, Details);

            //Saving to db
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IND492\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeaveMgmt;Integrated Security=True");
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into LeaveDetailsTable values (@leave_details)", con);
                con.Open();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@leave_details", bytes);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Now I have a doubt that which Datatype I should choose while Storing in database ? 
Actually I used the table LeaveDetailsTable(L_ID int , leave_details nvarchar(50))

But It is showing the error while retrieving from database as

**System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.**

Code for retrieving from database is :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IND492\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeaveMgmt;Integrated Security=True");
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select leave_details from LeaveDetailsTable where L_ID=1", con);
                con.Open();
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                ms.Position = 0;
                List<LeaveDetails> mc = (List<LeaveDetails>)bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Comment: Now I changed the Table to LeaveDetailstable(L_ID int , leave_details varbinary(MAX)). But It Showing Error in Deserialize code as  **" Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader.Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization"**. Changes?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can read, so it should be quite obvious, or?

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 
>   'System.Byte[]'.

Serieaization (standard, not XML / XAML) is binary. As such, varchar does not work. Use varbinary. Varbinary returns as byte array.

Comment: Now , the Error is "Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization."

Comment: If you tell me where is the problem in code, that will be more helpful. Thank You!!

Comment: @developer Dude, this is aQ&A site, not a Consulting site. You asked a question, got an answer. Want to have another question asked, make a code sample and ask a question. As a tip - start by making a unit test (always good) and comparing the Arrays you write in and get out.