# BULK INSERT permission denied - BLOB vs FILESTREAM

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, database-administration

My company is very strict when it comes to security. My project, (built using VB.Net and SQL Server 2008) requires that users upload PDF files which then need to be stored into the database along with the associated path.  Because the files will be just about 256kb or less, I wanted to insert the files as `Single BLOB`.  My table has two columns Path as `varchar(50)` and `File` as `varbinary(max)`.  My SQL query looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [DBNAME].[dbo].[SOMETABLE](PATH, FILE)
values ('C:\Somefile.pdf', (SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Somefile.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB)
AS import ))
```

Unfortunately, I only have read and write permissions on the database, thus yielding the following error: `You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.` I have read this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23599/bulk-insert-permission-on-a-single-database) but for other security reasons, I will not be granted `Insert` or `ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS`  permissions.  From other posts that I have read, without the permissions this option seems to be a dead end.

Now, I am looking into using `FILESTREAM` to insert the files but will not be able to create a new database. Can I accomplish this by enabling `FILESTREAM` on an existing database and database table and work with those? I have been on this for two days, any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't create a new database, I'm guessing they won't let you alter an existing database either.  You can add FILESTREAM capabilities, but it requires that you at least create a new FILEGROUP.  It also requires that the server configuration be changed if it isn't already set up to support FILESTREAM capabilities.  Again, this sounds unlikely in the environment you describe.  Also, FILESTREAM is generally recommended for larger files (>1 MB) then the 256KB you mention.

Since they are so strict in your environment you might try loading the document into your VB front end, encoding it and storing it to the database from there as a byte data insert from there.  It won't require the BLOB/BULK insert and sounds like it might be a better alternative in such a restricted environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Correct, everything you stated in the first paragraph I am unable to do.  I am currently loading the files into my front end in VB using 'DragEnter' and 'DragDrop' on a simple textbox object.  If I were to encode it and insert, would I be able to get the actual file say if a user accidentally deleted it from the server itself?

Comment: If they deleted the row in the database that stored that record then no, it would be gone, only to be retrieved from a database backup.  But it would be the same with BLOB or FILESTREAM entries.  The ability for users to delete data should always be tightly controlled and extensive logging to track such things used.  It will save your butt some day when they blame you for missing records, as end users are fond of doing.

Comment: I should've been more specific, what I meant to say was if they removed it from the folder itself not the row in the db as they won't have access to that. Can you provide me with an example of how to do this?

Comment: Ah, you just save the file to the database as a byte stream.  To pull it out, you just pull the byte stream out and save it as a file.  You'll probably want to store file info (name, extension, etc) in the database table with the byte array.  Examples to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp   and    http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/convert-file-to-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-files/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not just load the file up via normal SQL statements and binary array? The size is small enough for this and it means that you only need access to the files from your app, not the server needs to find and read them.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example on how to do this? Also, would that save the actual file itself, in case it were to be deleted by a user with access to that specific path? (Again, security reasons)