# what is the encode standard of .DOCX? (encode and save string to database) C#

Tags: c#, stream, devexpress, docx

i want to save in a database (mssql) the info of my HTMLEDITOR but when i encode the data and save it's  fine,  but when i restore it or open it  data, they not open nothing.
i think the problem it's the enconde standard.

```
      using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string docx = string.Empty;
            byte[] bytesDocx = null;

            this.ASPxHtmlEditorTemplate.Export(HtmlEditorExportFormat.Docx, output);//pass the data of the editor and assign to stream
            output.Flush();
            output.Position = 0;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(output))
            {
                docx = reader.ReadToEnd();// assign the stream to a STRING
                bytesDocx = Encoding.UTF-8.GetBytes(docx);//encode the STRING to UTF-8

                using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
                {
                    //here some instructions to save the "bytes" to TEXT in a MSSQL DB
                    uow.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you either to store the `*.docx` as XML document(because it is really XML):

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(docxStream);
string text = xmldoc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
```

or to store stream' bytes directly to database without any "to-string" conversion using the technique described in [Save byte[] into a SQL Server database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp) article.