# VB.net SQL Server Upload PDF

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am looking to upload a PDF from my VB.Net program to SQL Server. I have the below code.

the file I need to upload needs to go into the uDoc column and the file path (C:\example.pdf) is the string inDoc.

any ideas on how to complete my code.

Thanks
Rob

```
Sub UploadInvoice()
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim inAcc As String
    Dim inType As String
    Dim inDoc As String


    inAcc = Form1.tb1Account.Text
    inType = frmInv.cbType.Text
    inDoc = frmInv.tbFile.Text



    myConn = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    myConn.Open()

    Dim mycmd As New SqlCommand

    mycmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblInvoice (UDate, AccNo, Type, UDoc) VALUES(GETDATE(),'" & inAcc & "','" & inType & "','" & inDoc & "')"




    mycmd.Connection = myConn
    mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What you have is a wide-open SQL injection vulnerability.  You can fix it by using "parameterized queries" instead of directly concatenating strings like that.  This will also help you fix your problem because then you can convert the binary file to a `byte[]` and assign it to a parameter.  Which is going to be *a lot* easier then putting a `byte[]` directly into a query string.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on "parameterized queries" however the application is only used by one person on a closed network, but i will bear that in mid for the future.

once i have changed it how would i add the byte file?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that it's vulnerable.  And it *especially* doesn't change the fact that it advertises an insecure coding practice as being "acceptable" which can cause much more damage than this one application.  Also there's the part about how using parameterized queries is exactly how to do what you're trying to do...  For example, the answer here shows how to use a byte array as a query parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

If this is an ASP.Net application, use the FileUpload control. It emits a file input field  in the browser so you can select a file (or multiple if using .Net 4.5 and an HTML5 compliant browser). You won't be able to get the full file path, but that is generally irrelevant since a web application has no ability to read a client file system. Save the uploaded file to a location and store that location in the db.