# c# put a byte[] into an database and retrive later

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, wpf

In my c# wpf project I have a byte array which needs to be stored in a database and converted back to a bytearray. What is the right approach for storing byte arrays? My query looks like:

```
string query = "UPDATE sometable SET file= @File  WHERE identifier =   @identifierwhere";

upsert = new SqlCommand(query, _connector.getMsConnection());
upsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@identifier", v.UniqueIdentifier));
upsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@File  ", filestring""));

filestring i made like:

if (v.File != null)
{
    fileString = GetStringFromBytes(v.File);
}
```

I use this function

```
static string GetStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

When i look in my database all i see is one letter 'A' when debbuging i see the value of filestring containse 'chinese?' characters. 
What is the right way to store and retrive a byte array?

Comment: Why make it a string? Why not just save the bytes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save byte\[\] into a SQL Server database from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Funny how things fare differently at different points in time. 3 close votes (before mine for duplicate), but [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp) from 2010 has lots of upvotes. Also, I don't see why all the close votes, unless we'd close as a duplicate. How is this off topic? OP gave minimal code and an explanation of what he tried.

Comment: @MillieSmith not all systems are great. [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310511)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [BINARY or VARBINARY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) to store binary data.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Content) VALUES(@Content)";

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/*yout connection string here*/))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
    param.Value = YourByteArrayVariableHere;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

You could retrieve it by using a SqlDataReader to get data and than cast the result as byte array. This code gets only the first row. If you want to get more use `while (d.Read())` instead of the `if (d.Read())`.

```
string query = "Select Content from dbo.MyTable";
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/*your connection string here*/))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader d = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (d.Read())
        {
            byte[] byteArray = (byte[])d["Content"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think he doesn't?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Because of his `GetStringFromBytes` and `GetBytesFromString` method he removed a few seconds ago. And he asks for the right way to store bytes in a database.

Comment: How should i Retrive it? im storing it now just as a bytearray in a text value as other people suggested to remove the conversion function

Comment: @SvenB I updated my answer. Hope it helps.