# Save Image File Into Database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, arrays

I'm trying to save image file into database using wpf mvvm. I use FileStream to read the image file and save in byte[] as below:

```
data = new byte[fs.Length];
```

Then, I pass the value through parameter to a save method. When I run the program and trace it with Profiler, I realize that the byte[] is becoming as below:

```
exec dbo.InsertImage N'System.Byte[]',N'.png'
```

The byte[] that I get in debug is binary. I have no idea why it becomes System.Byte[] when try to execute the query. Can anyone give some explanation and provide solution to me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show the code for the save method

Comment: My method is very simple only. It is use to invoke stored procedure and pass the parameters into the stored proc. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting "System.Byte[]" because that is what you get when you do `data.ToString()`. My guess is that whatever method you're using to save this byte array to the database doesn't know how to handle the `byte[]` type, so it just calls `ToString()` on it.

Take a look at this answer which shows how to save a `byte[]` into SQL Server. [Save byte[] into a SQL Server database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp)

Then, check your save method to make sure that it can properly handle `byte[]`.