# C# saving whole outlook .msg file in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, outlook

Is there anyway how to save whole `.msg` file with attachments from Outlook into a SQL Server database?

I am able to send MailItem objects into database.

```
Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace _ns = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MailItem item = _ns.GetItemFromID(selectedMailEntryId);

string sentOn = item.SentOn.ToLongDateString() + " " + item.SentOn.ToLongTimeString();

if (ServicesMail.InsertMail(txtSenderName.Text, txtSenderAddress.Text, item.Subject, txtQuestions.Text, txtAnswers.Text, item.HTMLBody, sentOn))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your Mail has been successfully saved in databse.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

and this is the query.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO EmailStorage (fullName, emailAddress, questions, answers, htmlBody, sentOn, savedOn, subject)
                    VALUES(@fullName, @emailAddress, @questions, @answers, @htmlBody, @sentOn, @savedOn, @subject)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", fullName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", emailAddress);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questions", questions);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answers", answers);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@htmlBody", htmlBody);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentOn", sentOn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@savedOn", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", subject);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It works perfectly. But I need to store whole message, so I can take it from database when needed and open it in Outlook.

Looked at many resources, but only found how to store it locally. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You might be able to save the .msg file as a [VarBinary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp), but why would you? File storage is much better suited for storing ... files.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this article. When you use AddWithValue for pass through queries like this it will sometimes get the wrong datatype. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, call `MailItem.SaveAs(..., olMsg)` to save as a local file, then read the file data into a buffer or stream and set binary field's value.