# Finger print Image conversion to byte C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been working on a finger print project. The code below can convert finger print image to a byte array, but if you take the finger print of say three people the value that will be submitted is the same value, it is not unique. It is supposed to be unique per person since we will need to verify each person with it. Any help will be appreciated pls.

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    @fname = txtfname.Text;
    @lname = txtlname.Text;

    byte[] @img1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(pictureBox1.Image));    

    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-400N4CL;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.fingerp " + " (fname,lname,finprint) " + " VALUES(@fname,@lname,@img1)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtfname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtlname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img1", @img1);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Your details is captured successfully");
    ////txtfname.Text = "";
    txtlname.Text = "";
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
```

Comment: It would only be the same if it's the same image. Why would 3 different people use the same image 3 times?

Comment: `Convert.ToString(pictureBox1.Image)` **does not get the image data** - that's why the values are all the same, as they're based on the string "System.Drawing.Bitmap"

Comment: Note: you might be underestimating the logic involved in comparing fingerprints.

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToString()` is not going to get the byte array of your image, but the type (System.Drawing.Bitmap).Try this method to convert your image to a byte array:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
     using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
           imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
           return ms.ToArray();
     }
}
```

Anyway, if you are going to compare the stored image with a new one for recognition, this is not going to work i'm afraid,as 2 scanned images of the same fingerprint won't share the same bytes.

**Edit**

In your comments you say you've got another problem: the row is not being saved when you add the byte array to the parameters. You can't do it with `AddWithValue`, you'll need something like this for that parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img1", SqlDbType.VarBinary,0, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "img1", DataRowVersion.Current, DBNull.Value));
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp) for more info.

Comment: I have tried that method before but it never work. I did not save. maybe am placing it in a wrong place in my code. where do you think I place it. or what more can I do make it work pls?

Comment: If it does not save,it may be because the colum type in your database...

Comment: The colum type in the database is varbinary(max)

Comment: Look at the error after using the method and corrections above: Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'finprint', table 'test.dbo.fingerp'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. Look at the code arrangement: the method was placed above the btn_save method which contain other values such as fname and lname.