# Store and retrieve cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, session-cookies

My C# app is doing some work on website. I would like to use same cookie instead of creating new one every time I run my application. I would like to save cookie into database or serialize it.

The code is:

```
CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

private string getRequest(string url, CookieContainer cookie, string postData = "")
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    StreamReader reader;

    var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14";
    request.CookieContainer = cookie;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    postData = Uri.EscapeUriString(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    Byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    foreach (Cookie tempCookie in response.Cookies)
    {
        cookie.Add(tempCookie);
    }

    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string readerReadToEnd = reader.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();

    foreach (Cookie _cookie in response.Cookies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. Version: {0}", _cookie.Version);
        Console.WriteLine("2. Value: {0}", _cookie.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("3. TimeStamp: {0}", _cookie.TimeStamp);
        Console.WriteLine("4. Secure: {0}", _cookie.Secure);
        Console.WriteLine("5. Port: {0}", _cookie.Port);
        Console.WriteLine("6. Path: {0}", _cookie.Path);
        Console.WriteLine("7. Name: {0}", _cookie.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("8. HttpOnly: {0}", _cookie.HttpOnly);
        Console.WriteLine("9. Expires: {0}", _cookie.Expires);
        Console.WriteLine("10. Expired: {0}", _cookie.Expired);
        Console.WriteLine("11. Domain: {0}", _cookie.Domain);
        Console.WriteLine("12. Discard: {0}", _cookie.Discard);
        Console.WriteLine("13. CommentUri: {0}", _cookie.CommentUri);
        Console.WriteLine("14. Comment: {0}", _cookie.Comment);
        Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", _cookie.ToString());
    }

    return readerReadToEnd;
}
```

When I run my application I am working with the same instance of `cookie`. But when I run application again the cookie is different. I would like to use always the same one.

Console output gives me this:

```
1. Version: 0
2. Value: rujd49p08kthfcuf7itdgnhkap5jideg
3. TimeStamp: 2016-11-25 21:58:06
4. Secure: False
5. Port: 
6. Path: /
7. Name: PHPSESSID
8. HttpOnly: True
9. Expires: 0001-01-01 00:00:00
10. Expired: False
11. Domain: example-site.com
12. Discard: False
13. CommentUri: 
14. Comment: 
String: PHPSESSID=rujd49p08kthfcuf7itdgnhkap5jideg
```

So my question is: can I save my cookie and use the same cookie for example 1 day later?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the `CookieContainer` to disk using a `BinaryFormatter`:

```
var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
var wstr = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\some\location\cookies.bin");
bf.Serialize(wstr, cookieContainer);
wstr.Close();
```

Then you can read the collection back from the saved file on a later run of the application (or whenever):

```
var rstr = File.OpenRead(@"C:\some\location\cookies.bin");
var cookieContainer = (CookieContainer)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(rstr);
```

Then you can assign that deserialized cookieContainer to the `HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer` before you make your request, and it will use the stored cookies - **if** those cookies aren't expired by the time you are trying to use them again.

The PHPSESSID cookie you mention is a session cookie without an explicit expiry - you *can* save it and re-use it the way you want to here, but it will still only actually *work* for as long as the PHP at the server considers that session to be valid.

Also, you shouldn't need to do this in your code:

```
foreach (Cookie tempCookie in response.Cookies)
{
    cookie.Add(tempCookie);
}
```

You've already set `request.CookieContainer = cookie` in your code (where `cookie` is a `CookieContainer`) - with that done, the cookies received in the response are automatically getting put into the `CookieContainer`, you don't need to do this manually.

Comment: Wow, thanks for answer. I am wondering if there is any way to store my cookies in SQL server database, for examply by saving as bytes. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: There are a number of ways that you could store the serialized representation in SQL:

Comment: You'd still use the BinaryFormatter, but you'd write to a `MemoryStream` and then call `ToArray()` on it to get the array of raw bytes of the serialized representation. From there you could store it in SQL in a `binary`/`varbinary` field, or you could call `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)` to turn it into a base64 string that could be stored in a plain old `varchar` or `nvarchar` field and then turned back into the byte array form with `FromBase64String()`. You can ultimately use the BinaryFormatter to serialize/deserialize your `CookieContainer` to any kind of stream.

Comment: There's an answer describing how to insert a `byte[]` to a SQL `varbinary` field using a parameterized query [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4057802/3794319).