# Decrypting stored in database encrypted data throws exception, using AES Encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, .net-core

I'm using Aes to encrypt and decrypt data. I have tested my Encrypt and Decrypt functions and they work, but when I try to decrypt stored in my database data it throws me

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The input data is
> not a complete block.

What I do before storing the bytes encryption is

```
string encryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_securityService.AesEncryptToBytes(data));
// Proceed in adding the encryptedData to the database.
```

This is how I decrypt my encrypted data pulled from the database.

```
string data = _securityService.AesDecryptFromBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedDataPulledFromMyDataBase));
```

My encryption method:

```
public byte[] AesEncryptToBytes(string plainText)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }
```

My Decryption method:

```
public string AesDecryptFromBytes(byte[] cipherText)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
```

What I've done is basically copy pasting the code from Microsoft Docs. Both methods work when testing them, but when I try to Decrypt the Encrypted data `which is the encryption bytes converted to string` I get thrown the exception.

Comment: AES is a block cipher, this means encrypted and therefore decrypted data (blocks) will have a fixed length. If I remember correctly it's even the key size. That is why there is often padding in data, pretty much you fill up with specific data until you reach your block size. My guess is that somewhere the block size is not correct.

Comment: does that mean that Aes is useless if I want to store my encrypted data in a database ?

Comment: No, it just depends how you save data in your database. It's binary data, putting any encoding on it before storing, picking the right type for the data in your database and putting any encoding reading the data from the database will break it if you are not careful. So just save the byte array plain and read it plain. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057802/13687491

Comment: `string encryptedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...)`: A ciphertext must not be UTF8 decoded, as this will corrupt the data. If you want to convert the ciphertext to a string, you have to use a suitable enocding, e.g. Base64. Or store the ciphertext as binary data.

Comment: @nanu_nana It's the block size, not the key size. And it depends on the mode of operation if the ciphertext must be a multiple of that block size or not. If there is a problem with decryption, the block size is not likely in error. Usually it is an encoding error - like we're seeing now.

Comment: Additionally, it appears to me that the location of the `encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();` is in the wrong spot. It should be immediately after the closing brace for the `using` statement that manages the CryptoStream object. Only then can you be certain that the crypto buffers and final crypto block have been properly processed. Although I have to admit, after reading the .Net documentation, I really have no idea what happens when `Dispose()` is called on the StreamWriter. Does it called `Close()` on the underlying stream?

Comment: "This method disposes the stream, by writing any changes to the backing store and closing the stream to release resources." It's a generic method. They apparently overwrote it and didn't copy the docs.

Comment: Changing the type of the column in the database, that stores the encrypted data to `VARBINARY` and just directly inserting the `encrypted to bytes` data fixed the problem. @nanu_nana or someone else if you want to write an answer, so I accept.