# How to save image in database which datatype to use

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I am saving images into sql server database. Images are saved but the data of all are same that is

```
   0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D.
```

I have used Image data type to store images. Should i use varbinary(Max) to save image?

Please provide some suggestion.

Comment: Images are stored as binary data in SQL Server. How would you _expect_ them to be stored?

Answer (score 1):

Your hexadecimal data decodes to the string `System.Byte[]`. You're saving your byte array incorrectly.

See for example [Save byte[] into a SQL Server database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057748/save-byte-into-a-sql-server-database-from-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use `varbinary(Max)` to save image?

Yes, but not because the data type is different. Images are stored as varbinary data in SQL server, but the datatype [will be removed in a future version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You'll *see* the data exactly the same as a varbinary column, but you'll be protected from the deprecated column type if you ever upgrade the server version,